# Microsoft Access Error fetching next row

Tags: ms-access

I am running in query in microsoft access 2013 that joins a large table with 5 columns (20 mil entries) and a smaller table with 5 columns (1 mil entries). The following is the query I am running.

```
SELECT * FROM
smallTable AS a INNER JOIN largeTable AS b ON a.id = b.id
```

When it runs, the query takes about 3 minutes to complete. My problem is that about 50% of the time, I get this error:

```
ODBC--call failed.
FATAL: terminating connection due to conflict with recovery
User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed.;
Error fetching next row (#26)
```

Right now, I just retry the query til it works, but I am wondering if there is a way to work around this error. Thanks!

Comment: What backend database are you linking to?  Also, if I may ask, what you will do with the results since visually browsing through a million records seems less "efficient".  Can you apply selection criteria to reduce number of rows?

Comment: I have filtered the smallTable down by the parts that I need, so I have a table of about 1000 parts. largeTable is a table of every part quoted. I want to join the tables and yield a list of every quote for those 1000 parts. Expected around 10000 quotes for 1000 parts in the result. After this, I still get the same error about 50% of the time

Comment: *What backend database are you linking to?*

Comment: Im not sure. I am connecting through ODBC to Machine Data Source to Our data warehouse

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the questions posted by C Perkins - keep in mind that Access is a front end database.  All those records transfer & process in your front end PC and so you would need a very big sized RAM and good processing to run 4M record joining 1M.

Today's PCs are very powerful but you could be stressing your hardware at this high level payload.